# Doka Image Editor not outputting file when using onconfirm

Tags: angular, typescript, filepond

I'm trying to get a base64 string from an image file I edited using [docs](https://pqina.nl/doka/blog/converting-a-file-to-a-base64-string/) from Doka image editor.

This is the code I'm using from the link

```
     options = {
    class: 'my-filepond',
    multiple: true,
    labelIdle: 'Drop images here',
    allowImagePreview: true,
    acceptedFileTypes: 'image/jpeg, image/png',
    allowFileEncode: true,
    allowImageTransform: true,
    imageEditEditor: Doka.create({
      cropAspectRatio: 1,
      allowFileEncode: true,
      outputFile: true,
      onconfirm: (output) => {

        const file = output.file;

        // encode the file using the FileReader API
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = () => {

          // use a regex to remove data url part
          const base64String = reader.result as string;
          base64String.replace('data:', '')
            .replace(/^.+,/, '');

          // log to console
          console.log(base64String) // logs wL2dvYWwgbW9yZ...

        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
    })
  };

  files = [
  ]

  handleFilePondInit() {
    console.log('FilePond has initialised', this.myPond);
  }

  handleFilePondAddFile(event: any) {

    console.log(event.file.getFileEncodeBase64String());

  }
```

Currently I'm getting the error

```
Property 'replace' does not exist on type 'string | ArrayBuffer'.
  Property 'replace' does not exist on type 'ArrayBuffer'
```

The reason I'm getting this error is because when I 
`console.log(output)` from `onconfirm` it shows

[image]

The Doka docs from link above show that you have to assign `const file = output.file` , but as you can see in image above, file doesn't exist as a property. How can I get the file to appear in the Doka `onconfirm` so that I can create a base64 url? I appreciate any help!

Comment: If you're using Doka with FilePond you can use the FilePond file encode plugin to create a base64 string

Comment: I updated my question and original code to add more of it and to add additional details that I left out. Doka create event doesn't have getFileEncodeBase64String() like filepond does and it doesn't run ```handleFilePondAddFile(event: any)``` after using Doka so I can't get base64 via filepond. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: When using Doka with FilePond, FilePond will do the image transform (create the output file) so in your `onconfirm` handler `output.file` will be undefined. You need to use the FilePond FileEncode plugin you can use `onupdatefiles` or `onpreparefile` to know when a file is updated.

Comment: I tried the following, but the console.log inside onpreparefile and onupdatefiles doesn't output the label or the value so it's not outputting any of the console.logs. I must be doing something wrong. I was referencing this https://pqina.nl/doka/docs/patterns/faq/converting-a-file-to-a-base64-string/  when using onconfirm to get dataUrl. The dataUrl is what I need to get ```[src]``` to work in angular. I was confused earlier. Here's my update code. Why is onpreparefile not outputting the edited image? https://pastebin.com/nhRpRm6q  I appreciate the help!